# python3 + pip3 + install vklancer

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, администрирование

Сразу скажу, что модуль успешно устанавливался под ubuntu 15.10.

Заказал VPS, ОС ubuntu-14.04-x86_64-minimal.
Сделал apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install aptitude
(aptitude для корректной установки pip3 иначе выдает различные ошибки на моем ПК)
Далее поставил pip3 через aptitude (потом пытался и через apt-get install python3-pip) и, собственно, пытаюсь установить нужный мне модуль для Python3, т.е. "vklancer" (для работы с vk api).
Как бы я ни пробовал (через setup.py или pip3), установка заканчивается такой ошибкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
root@istrueorfalse:~# pip3 install vklancer
Downloading/unpacking vklancer
  Downloading vklancer-1.3.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/vklancer/setup.py) egg_info for package vklancer
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/vklancer/setup.py", line 22, in <module>
        long_description = f.read()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 264: ordinal not in range(128)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/vklancer/setup.py", line 22, in <module>

    long_description = f.read()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode

    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 264: ordinal not in range(128)

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/vklancer
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
root@istrueorfalse:~#
```

В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что у Вас где-то python2 вызывается (`python setup.py`), в Ubuntu 3-й питон вызывается командой `python3`, а просто `python` - это 2-й.

Comment: П.С. В 3-ем (я его особо не применяю), ИМХО, такая ошибка просто невозможна.

Comment: Так я и запускаю через 3ий 
http://imgur.com/L5olapQ

Comment: покажите вывод "echo $LANG" , если будет не UTF-8 , то стоит переключиться на неё

Answer (score 1):

Решилось. Нужно ставить локаль нормально, а именно выполнить переустановку locale и выбрать Русский язык. У меня все заработало.